# how to use java mail api with apache v9.0

Tags: java, tomcat

Basically i have apache 9 configured with java ee, what i want is to send a mail to an email using java mail api. but the problem is that when i input my java mail api code to send a simple mail saying `email sent successfuly` i get an apache error saying:

> Starting Tomcat v9.0 Servet at localhost has encountered a problem.
>   Server tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

here is my java mail api code:

```
 public void AMail(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
 {
 String to = "example@gmail.com";
 String from = "Account@domain.com";
 String host = "localhost";
 Properties properties = System.getProperties();
 properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
 response.setContentType("text/html");
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

 try{
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                      new InternetAddress(to));
  message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
  message.setText("This is actual message");
  Transport.send(message);
  String title = "Send Email";
  String res = "Sent message successfully....";
  String docType =
  "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
  "transitional//en\">\n";
  out.println(docType +
  "<html>\n" +
  "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
  "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
  "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
  "<p align=\"center\">" + res + "</p>\n" +
  "</body></html>");
 }catch (MessagingException mex) {
  mex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
```

for as long as i have this function in my code i get the apache above error.

Comment: Please add your tomcat start log

Comment: i have nothing in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs